# Area inside the astroid

Tags: area, parametric

I need to find area inside the astroid: 
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x=2\cos^3(\frac t 4) \\ 
y=2\sin^3(\frac t 4)
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
I've seen some formulas with integrals, but the first problem I run into is I've been trying to draw it with online services but (as far as I can understand) problem with $\frac t 4$ instead of simply $t$ what I see in all astroid equation. 
So, for the beginning, is my $\frac t 4$ ok? Should I perceive it as regular argument? 
How should I get my astroid draft? How to get points for drawing maybe?
Next is which formula or way should I use to calculate this area? Because on one site, I stumbled upon this formula: 
$S=\frac {3\pi ab} {8}$
Is that correct? Can I use it?

Thanks to all in advance!

Comment: $(\frac x3)^{2/3}+(\frac y2)^{2/3}=1$

Comment: Excuse me, what is that exactly? It's for calculating $ds$, right? Why precisely these numbers?

Comment: Its the cartesian equation.

Comment: It is similar to one asked in Putnam 1939. Also see here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66027/how-can-i-calculate-area-of-astroid-represented-by-parameter

Comment: thanks, but what should I do with this cartesian equation?

Comment: You asked how to get points for drawing.

Comment: Ok, that was one of questions. I also asked about area formula, which I gave, is it correct?

Comment: Also can you explain me, what effect does that argument $t$ is dividing by 4 in my case?

Comment: see here you can find the cumputations
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428246/calculating-area-of-astroid-x2-3y2-3-a2-3-for-a0-using-greens-th

Comment: In this if $0\le  t/4\le 2\pi$ then $0\le t \le 8\pi$. It changes the range of definite integral. I think your formula is correct.

Comment: Thanks, I dont' know why I didn't understand it by myself! :)

Comment: You can calculate the are using definite integrals the formula used will be $$\frac 12\int_a^b(xy'-x'y) dt$$ where $a$ and $b$ are values through which parameter $t$ goes.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter what parameter you use.  You can define $u=\frac t4$ and use $u$.  You will get the same points.  The formula give you a nice astroid, as plotted by [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric%20plot%7B%20x%3D(cos(t%2F4))%5E3,%20y%3D(sin(t%2F4))%5E3%7D)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For calculating the area of your astroid, I would first consider transforming the eqations in one like this:

$x=2\cos^3(\frac{t}{4})\Rightarrow (\frac{x}{2})^{2/3}=\cos^2(\frac{t}{4})$

$y=2\sin^3(\frac{t}{4})\Rightarrow (\frac{y}{2})^{2/3}=\sin^2(\frac{t}{4})$

now you have $(\frac{x}{2})^{2/3}+(\frac{y}{2})^{2/3}=1$.

Because of the propreties from the trigonometric functions, you know that it's enough to calculate one forth of the astroid, bcs it's symetrical. We will calculate the part where $x>0$ and $y>0$, so: $y=(2^{2/3}-x^{2/3})^{3/2}$.
Now we get that $$\int_0^2 (2^{2/3}-x^{2/3})^{3/2} = \frac{3\pi}{8}$$

So the area of the whole astroid is $\frac{3\pi}{2}$.