# Area of astroid given in parametric form

Tags: definite-integrals, parametric

Find the area of the region bounded by the astroid, in parametric form, $(x;y)=(2cos^3 t; 2sin^3 t)$

Well, I used the formula of area given in parametric curves $\int_a^b y(t).x'(t) \,dt$. So, as it's an astroid, I know that I can find the area between $[0; \pi ]$ and multiply it by 2. Then, after differentiating and replacing, I get $2 \int_0^\pi 2sin^3(t).(-6cos^2(t)sin(t)) \,dt$

which can be written as $-24 \int_0^\pi sin^4(t).cos^2(t) \,dt$

The thing is that I integrated using trigonometric identities, but it was really tedious, and, to top it, it was wrong, because when I differentiated the result I didn't get the first function and the area was negative.

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66027/how-can-i-calculate-area-of-astroid-represented-by-parameter

Comment: You might have an easier time of it if you use $\frac12(x\,dy-y\,dx)$ as the integrand.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I’m not sure that question helps much. The OP is already trying to use the method given in the accepted answer; the issue appears to be in the details of the actual calculation.

Comment: The sign of your answer came out wrong because you left out a negative sign in the first place. As to why the value is otherwise incorrect, you’ll have to show your work for anyone to be able to point out your error.

Answer (score 1):

We can dispense with the reason that you ended up with a negative area easily: you left a negative sign out in the first place. Referring to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/66039/265466) to an almost-identical question, the area of the astroid within the first quadrant is $-\int_0^{\pi/2} x'(t) y(t) \,dt$. The negative sign appears because $x$ decreases as $t$ increases from $0$ to $\frac\pi2$.

As for the rest, it’s impossible to say why you ended up with the wrong value without seeing your work. However, I think you could’ve made it a bit easier on yourself by using a different area element. The symmetries of $\sin$ and $\cos$ to me suggest using a more balanced volume element, namely $\frac12(x\,dy-y\,dx)$, or $$\frac12 \begin{vmatrix}x(t)&y(t)\\x'(t)&y'(t)\end{vmatrix} dt = \frac12\left(x(t)y'(t)-y(t)x'(t)\right) dt.$$ You can visualize this as the area of the infinitesimal triangle with sides defined by the vectors $(x,y)$ and $(x+dx,y+dy)$, i.e., an approximation to the area swept out by the radius vector $\mathbf r(t)=\left(x(t),y(t)\right)$ between $t$ and $t+dt$. For the astroid, the integrand is therefore $$\begin{align}\frac12 \begin{vmatrix}2\cos^3t & 2\sin^3t \\ -6\cos^2t\sin t & 6\cos t\sin^2t\end{vmatrix} &= 6\left(\cos^4t\sin^2t+\cos^2t\sin^4t\right) \\ &= 6\cos^2t\sin^2t \\ &= \frac32\sin^2{2t}, \end{align}$$ which can be simplified further to $\frac34(1-\cos{4t})$ using the identity $\cos{2\theta} = 1-2\sin^2\theta$.